# Помогите найти и исправить ошибку в задаче(цикл for и массивы)

Tags: java

[image: Сама задача]
[image: Мое решение с ошибкой]

Только начал изучать массивы и толком не знаю как их лучше вводить в этой задаче, пробовал уже все, но так и ничего не получается. Скорее всего ошибка именно в заполнении массива. Благодарю заранее за любую помощь.

Comment: О заголовке. По нему ориентируются, просматривая темы. А что можно понять из крика о помощи? По названию должна быть понятна задача

Comment: Если вы хотите получить толковый ответ на свой вопрос, то 1) в заголовке сформулируйте кратко суть вопроса, в первом абзаце -- чуть подробнее. Иначе многие, кто мог бы ответить, даже не заглянут в ваш вопрос и/или не будут вникать.  2) Не помешайте картинки в вопрос, помещайте текст. Из картинок нельзя скопировать код или текст сообщения об ошибке. Имейте в виду, что у большинства грамотных людей время дорого.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В условии цикла for нужно поставить i меньше, а не <= и далее в while элемента массива a[x] не существует.  В массиве из 5 элементов индексы считаются от 0, то есть [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], а элемента с индексом [5] нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь разобрался)